# Unity Drag and Drop from Inventory

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, drag-and-drop, spawn, inventory

I am very new to Unity so please excuse my amateur understanding of things. I am currently trying to implement an interface in unity 3d with an inventory including 2D icons which I want to drag and drop from the inventory which should then let the gameObejct spawn. I have tried to implement the exact codes from Jayanam on YouTube, adding you the links here:
Create inventory UI:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-xB4xEmGtCY&list=PLg7sMWZoap4B8N1pR8nl2-eG_D5k9MfWY

Inventory Script:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hj7AZkyojdo&list=PLg7sMWZoap4B8N1pR8nl2-eG_D5k9MfWY&index=2

Inventory UI Drag and Drop:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pc8K_DVPgVM&list=PLg7sMWZoap4B8N1pR8nl2-eG_D5k9MfWY&index=3

Drop Item:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=db6ofSbAXnE&list=PLg7sMWZoap4B8N1pR8nl2-eG_D5k9MfWY&index=4

Everything works fine, until I reach the point where I want to drop the Item. I can see that it calls the drop-function, but my gameObject doesn't spawn. I am adding you my codes here and I hope that someone might have the answer.

GameObject:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Child : MonoBehaviour, IInventoryItem
{
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return "Child";
        }
    }

    public Sprite _Image = null;

    public Sprite Image
    {
        get
        {
            return _Image;
        }
    }

    
    public void OnPickup()
    {
        // TODO: Add logic what happens when child stays in the sun for too long
        gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void OnDrop()
    {
        RaycastHit hit = new RaycastHit();
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1000))
       {
            gameObject.SetActive(true);
            gameObject.transform.position = hit.point;
        }
    }


}
```

HUD Script to handle the Inventory:

```
 using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class HUD : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Inventory Inventory;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        Inventory.ItemAdded += InventoryScript_ItemAdded;
        Inventory.ItemRemoved += Inventory_ItemRemoved;
    }

    private void InventoryScript_ItemAdded(object sender, InventoryEventArgs e)
    {
        Transform inventoryPanel = transform.Find("InventoryPanel");
        foreach(Transform slot in inventoryPanel)
        {
            // Border ... Image
            Transform imageTransform = slot.GetChild(0).GetChild(0);
            Image image = slot.GetChild(0).GetChild(0).GetComponent<Image>();
            ItemDragHandler itemDragHandler = imageTransform.GetComponent<ItemDragHandler>();

            // We found the empty slot
            if (!image.enabled)
            {
                image.enabled = true;
                image.sprite = e.Item.Image;

                // TODO: Store a reference to the item
                itemDragHandler.Item = e.Item;

                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Inventory_ItemRemoved(object sender, InventoryEventArgs e)
    {
        Transform inventoryPanel = transform.Find("InventoryPanel");
        foreach (Transform slot in inventoryPanel)
        {
            Transform imageTransform = slot.GetChild(0).GetChild(0);
            Image image = imageTransform.GetComponent<Image>();
            ItemDragHandler itemDragHandler = imageTransform.GetComponent<ItemDragHandler>();

            //We found the item in the UI
            if (itemDragHandler.Item.Equals(e.Item))
            {
                image.enabled = false;
                image.sprite = null;
                itemDragHandler.Item = null;
                break;

            }
        }
    }

    
}
```

Item Drag Handler to pull the Item Image out of the Inventory:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ItemDragHandler : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    public IInventoryItem Item { get; set; }
    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
            transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
    }
}
```

Item Drop Handler:

```
 using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ItemDropHandler : MonoBehaviour, IDropHandler
{
    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    { 
        RectTransform invPanel = transform as RectTransform;

        if(!RectTransformUtility.RectangleContainsScreenPoint(invPanel, Input.mousePosition))
        {
          Debug.Log("Drop item");
        }
    }


}
```

Inventory Script:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{
    private const int SLOTS = 4;

    private List<IInventoryItem> mItems = new List<IInventoryItem>();

    public event EventHandler<InventoryEventArgs> ItemAdded;

    public event EventHandler<InventoryEventArgs> ItemRemoved;

    //TODO: delete collider, Item should be picked up by mouse
    public void AddItem(IInventoryItem item)
    {
        if(mItems.Count < SLOTS)
        {
            Collider collider = (item as MonoBehaviour).GetComponent<Collider>();
            if (collider.enabled)
            {
                collider.enabled = false;

                mItems.Add(item);

                item.OnPickup();

                if (ItemAdded != null)
                {
                    ItemAdded(this, new InventoryEventArgs(item));
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void RemoveItem(IInventoryItem item)
    {
        if (mItems.Contains(item))
        {
            mItems.Remove(item);

            item.OnDrop();

            Collider collider = (item as MonoBehaviour).GetComponent<Collider>();
            if (collider != null)
            {
                collider.enabled = true;
            }

            if (ItemRemoved != null)
            {
                ItemRemoved(this, new InventoryEventArgs(item));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Inventory Item Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public interface IInventoryItem
{

    string Name { get; }

    Sprite Image { get; }

    void OnPickup();

    void OnDrop();
}

public class InventoryEventArgs: EventArgs
{
    public InventoryEventArgs(IInventoryItem item)
    {
        Item = item;
    }

    public IInventoryItem Item;
}
```

I would be really grateful if someone could help me out. I have been trying forever and I'm going crazy.

Comment: You added `ItemDragHandler` twice and `ItemDropHandler.OnDrop` doesn't do anything ... and I don't see at which point an object is supposed to be "spawned" .. you are only enabling and disabling stuff

Comment: The "Child" should spawn after IEndDragHandler is finished. This is why there is the IInventory class. It's connected to the GameObject to call the OnDrop function where the Object should appear but it doesn't.

Comment: well as said the `OnDrop` currently only chcks a position and logs something but it does nothing else .. especially not "spawn" anything

Comment: As I understood it shouldn't "spawn" something. It is just supposed to notify if the item is dropped outside the box and raise an event. Then the gameObject is notified and should appear. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Oh yeah sorry at first I didn't see the `Child` script .. hadn't noticed you have replaced it in the meantime ^^